# Is there a way to create bookmarks using text? (something like Wikimedia markup)

Tags: google-docs

Using Google Docs, when I click `Insert > Bookmark` I create a bookmark (duh!) in that place of the document, kind of a `<a name="here">cursor</a>`.

I have a few of these bookmarks in a document. I'd like to edit the document in an external editor (e.g., Notepad++) and paste it back to Google Docs, but then I face the problem of having to regenerate the bookmarks by hand.

Is there a way to indicate to the docs editor that I want a bookmark in a specific place? 
I'm thinking of something like

```
== here ==
```

and then

```
 [[#here|cursor]]
```

in Wikimedia style.

Comment: I'd offer a bounty if I were given the option

Comment: doing that, now that I can :)

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but a work-around: Create and maintain the documents in a plaintext format and use a third-party Google Drive application to edit them. I use Draft (draftin.com) for plain text files when I want collaborators and version control, and StackEdit (stackedit.io) for markdown documents with no special collaboration requirements.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is: **yes.** Hurray!

The medium-length answer is: yes, if have mad skillz. Aww, shucks.

### A more full answer

Through [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs), Google Docs is amazingly extensible. The lynchpin function you are seeking is aptly named `addBookmark()` ([class description here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#addBookmark(Position))). The function requires a passed value, however, and that is what will require some creativity.

In Pseudo-code, something like the following might work:

Prior to uploading the document to Google, designate the bookmarks you want with super-special-awesome markup that doesn't interfere with anything. Per your suggestion, let's pretend we know that enclosing in two equal signs will not cause you problems, so `== Special text to bookmark ==`. Upload the document. Run your script.

The script:

1. Starting at the top of the file, search the text of the document for a string pattern that matches `== [any text] ==`
2. When matching string is found, get the `Position` ([class description here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/position)) of the text
3. Use Position and run `addBookmark(Position)`
4. Continue with search of text until end of file
5. Announce the end of the script execution

For a competent programmer, this is not a particularly difficult task. Even though I can conceptualize the pseudo-code and read the class descriptions, if I tried to write this, I would certainly gain more gray hair.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that (and gain some gray-to-white hair in the process :)

Comment: I'm giving the +50 to you altough I didn't find the time to try it. Thanks for the reply (it looks promising)